# The html code coming from XML(converted into Json) is giving an object while I need to fetch just the data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, xml

XML:

```
<testText>
 <div>
   <h1>A heading</h1>
    <p>Enter text here</p>
 </div>
</testText>
```

I have to get the data from the XML that is inside the testText tag and display on the screen, however as I am converting the XML into json, the `<div>` tags are also considered as part of the XML and are getting converted into object. I have tried $sce, ngSanitize, data-bind-html.

JS :

```
var data= xmlToJs.xml("myXml.xml");

data.then(function(response){
$scope.textData= response.data.testText;
});
```

I tried this(and several other approaches listed) but did not work:

```
$scope,trustAsHtml =function(text){
 return $sce.trustAsHTML(text);
};
```

Instead of getting the div tags executed I get this on the screen :

{"div":{"h1":"A heading","p":"enter text here"}}

The data inside `<testText>` could be anything and we have no control over it.

Comment: Technically, the HTML **is** XML so everything you have shown is working correctly. So what are you expecting should happen when you convert your XML to JSON? If you have no control over the XML you probably need to find a different way of handling the XML all together.

Comment: Yes, we have other values coming from XML which work just fine and are what we need, its just when a HTML block of code comes in that I am running into trouble. It seems I might have to convert Json to Html but was wondering if there is any other way to handle this. I need the screen to show - A heading  enter text here

Comment: If that is the case, ideally the XML would put the HTML in a CDATA or some such but without that I'm not sure what your options would be.

Comment: In case I have a CData inside the <testText>, when converted to json it gives a blank. What can I do to read that ?

Comment: I guess that depends on what your `xmlToJs.xml()` is doing, which sounds like a separate question from the one you've posted. So you are able to change the XML now?